# Second order Euler diff. equation - how do I proceed with $y_p$ for this case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following equation $x^2 y'' - xy' +y = 6xlnx$

Once I introduce the following substitution - $x=e^t$, I get that the homogenous part of the solution is $y_h = C_1 e^t + C_2te^t$

But, how do I proceed next? If I wanted to solve the $y_p$ part by guessing the solution, I'd first transform the right side to be a function of $t$. Here is the right side of the equation then: $6e^tt$. Is this  correct? Now, how would I proceed with solving this but not by using variation of constants.

My guess would be that the particular solution is in the form of $6e^t * (At + B)$

Now, my concrete question is: **Do I have to multiply my guess by $t^2$ because I have a double solution that is equal to the coefficient of $t$ in the exponent of $e^t$
 because we have a product of $e^t$ and a polynomial of the first order.**

Comment: Yes exactly that for exactly the stated reason.

Comment: @LutzL so my guessed solution should actually be: $6e^t(At+B)t^2$ right? 

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, the transformed equation for $u(t)=y(e^t)$ is
$$
u''(t)-2u'(t)+u(t)=6te^t
$$
Alternatively to your method, apply $e^{-t}$ as integrating factor to get
$$
(e^{-t}u(t))''=6t\implies e^{-t}u(t)=t^3+A+Bt
$$
so that in the original variables
$$
y(t)=x(\ln x)^3+Ax+Bx\ln x.
$$